# Vitest: expect.closeTo is not a function

Tags: testing, sveltekit, vitest

I'm trying to use [`expect.toClose`](https://vitest.dev/api/expect.html#expect-closeto) from Vitest, but I'm getting `TypeError: expect.closeTo is not a function`.
According to the Typescript checks `Property 'closeTo' does not exist on type 'ExpectStatic'.ts(2339)`.
I'm using a fresh SvelteKit project with Vitest by default. The only change I've done was in the index.test.ts:

```js
import { describe, it, expect } from "vitest";

describe("sum test", () => {
  it("adds 1 + 2 to equal 3", () => {
    expect({ value: 1 + 2 }).toBe({
      value: expect.closeTo(3),
    });
  });
});
```

The dependencies are:

```json
{
"devDependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^2.0.0",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.27.4",
    "svelte": "^4.0.5",
    "svelte-check": "^3.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.0",
    "vite": "^4.4.2",
    "vitest": "^0.34.0"
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it should work in version 0.34. At least it works at 1.0.0-beta.4

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a recent issue, and it's probably fixed in the latest version.
Update your vitest to 0.34.6

https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/2809

Comment: Unfortunately, the error persists with 0.34.6